# Get last objects in a Spring many to many relationship

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, many-to-many, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring MVC app with a ManyToMany relationship between two tables, A and B. Given a B object I want to get the last ten A objects related to itself. Is this possible usign Spring-Data-JPA?  I have a lot of records in my DB so load all is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming your 'last' is a create date, you could use the following `findByBOrderByCreateDateDesc(Object B,Pageable pageable)` which would give you the *rough* equivalent or of what you're trying to do.

this approach ignores the many-to-many part and focuses on what is essentially a one-to-many in the context of the query.